# Wrap a material around a cube in Three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, cube

I have been following [this tutorial,](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-texture-with-three-js/) creating a Cube with a texture.
The problem is, the texture repeats on every face of the cube.
I would like to use a single texture that 'wraps' around the cube. Is this possible?

```
// material
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/crate.jpg')
});
// this has no effect!
material.wrapAround = true;

// cube
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);
cube.overdraw = true;
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;
scene.add(cube);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with a THREE.CubeGeometry, you can either:

(1) Choose a single texture that repeats on each side of the cube, or 
(2) Have a different texture for each of the six sides

You can also use repeat the number of times a texture is displayed on each side.

For examples of each of these, check out the source code of the demos at:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Textures.html

and

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Repeat.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it!